# Wrapping blake hash function C implementation into Python using ctypes module, simple python ctypes testvector script also included

Tags: python, c, hash, ctypes

I'm trying to make simple library blake hash function wrapper using python ctypes from C. But only for testing at first whether my simple C helper function would work correctly or not, I wrote  small python script blake hash function test vectors. And my problem arose with this small script. I'm stumbling upon at hours to resolve this problem. I always got unexpected of 64 bytes output value of "blake 512 usage" by using this small helper test vector script. I realize that, my problem is came from c helper function I wrote when trying to return amount of (and should be exact) 64 bytes for later would be used by using this small python ctypes script test vectors.

The pure C implementation source I used was downloaded directly from NIST Blake Submission for Optimiezed 32bit Processor under the name of files, blake_opt32.c and blake_opt32.h . And can be download here at http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/Round3/documents/Blake_FinalRnd.zip

And here is my simple C helper function for later to be called by using python ctypes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "blake_opt32.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

BitSequence msg[65];

size_t    strlcpy(unsigned char *dst, const char *src, size_t siz)
{
unsigned char *d = dst;
const char *s = src;
size_t n = siz;

/* Copy as many bytes as will fit */
if (n != 0) {
    while (--n != 0) {
        if ((*d++ = *s++) == '\0')
            break;
    }
}

/* Not enough room in dst, add NUL and traverse rest of src */
if (n == 0) {
    if (siz != 0)
        *d = '\0';      /* NUL-terminate dst */
    while (*s++)
        ;
}

return(s - src - 1);    /* count does not include NUL */
}

BitSequence * bl(char *input)
{
BitSequence output[65];
BitSequence msg[sizeof(output)];
int dInt;

memset(output,0,sizeof(output));
dInt = strlen(input);

if (dInt > 0xffff){
    exit( 1);
}
BitSequence data[dInt];

memset(data, 0, dInt);
strlcpy(data, input, sizeof(data));
DataLength dLen =1152;
Hash(512, data, dLen, output);
int x;
for (x=0;x<64;++x){
    printf("%02X",output[x]);
}
memcpy(msg,output,sizeof(output));
//here the problem araised, when trying to return unsigned char or BitSequence value, the unexpected output of small python scipt test vectors value is detected 
return  msg; 
}
```

And the simple small python script test vector is here, just try this small script by redirecting output to any text of file, later the unexpected value would be catched.

```
from ctypes import *
from string import printable
from itertools import permutations
from random import *
d = CDLL('blake.dll') #edit here your own dll or .so library
d.bl.restype = c_char_p

print '[+] Simple Test-vectors Blake hash function\n'
s = SystemRandom()
for x in permutations(printable):
p = ''.join(map(str,x))
q = list(p)
s.shuffle(q)
r= d.bl(''.join(map(str,q)))
if ((len(r)*2) != 0x80):
    print '\n[-] Not persistent value of 64 bytes was detected : %d'% len(r) 
    w = r.encode('hex')
    print w, '-->', len(w) 
    print '\n'
elif ((len(r)*2) == 0x80):
    print '\n',len(r), '\n',r.encode('hex')
    print '\n'
```

Therefore, any corrections of my helper C function above for later to be called using this small Python script test vector in order the output value  to be expected would be appreciated, thank you very much before!
By the way above is an updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the function `BitSequence * bl(char *input)`, The return value `output` is a local variable that won't exist after the function exits.

Comment: then, does the return value should be global variable?

Comment: Resloved little only from gcc warning messages, but by using the testvector above still, unexpected value detected many times....?